# Passing flow components to Apex class

Tags: screen-flow

How can i pass Multiselect picklist values selected by user on the flow screen to the Apex class
i am using the screen varaible of the picklist value in the Apex action but it is not getting assigned

```
// Revision Screen Flow Approach 
public class FlowInputs {
    @InvocableVariable public String scope;
    @InvocableVariable public String quoteid;
    @InvocableVariable public String temp;
}
@InvocableMethod (label = 'Quote Revision' description = 'Revision of the Quote.')
public static void QuoteRevision (List<FlowInputs> request) {
    String scope = String.valueOf(request[0].scope);
    String quoteid = String.valueOf(request[0].quoteid);
    String temp = String.valueOf(request[0].temp);
    system.debug('Scope: ==> '+scope); 
    system.debug('quoteid: ==> '+quoteid);
    system.debug('temp: ==> '+temp);
    system.debug('var: ==> '+var);
}
```

here the scope variable is for storing the Multiselect picklist selected by the user but not getting assigned with the value

On the Flow side iam taking the screen component (Scope) api id as the input to the apex method

[image: Apex Action]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] then [edit] your question to provide detail of what you have done and where you are stuck. Without such detail we cannot help you. Ideally provide code snippets and detail of the flow elements and resources in use as text. A screenshot of the over-all flow would also be useful.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code; add the code itself. The editor has help that tells you how to use markdown to denote the start and end of code blocks for example.